# Access the element of outer function in nested functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an each function that has change function and ajax inside..

```
$( ".spring_explorations" ).each(function() {
        $("#" + this.id + " select").change(function() {
            alert("t");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ('/admin/applications/get_sections_for_modal'), //pass query string to server
                data: {
                exploration_id: $("#" + this.id + " select").val()
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(this).parents('span').next().show();
                    $(this).parents('span').next().find("select").html(response);
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

I would like to access the `$(this)` element of `spring_explorations` class inside the `success` snippet of `ajax` script.

I was able to access the element of the `change` function by adding `context: this` but how can I get the element of the outer?

Thanks in advanced.

Edit:

The `$(this).parents('span').next().show();` and so on are undefined because maybe the `this` is the ajax itself not the `spring_explorations` class.

I'm very sorry if this is a duplicated question. I'm just fairly new in javascript and I think this is the right place to ask this thing. If you think this is not appropriate, just close my question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions.

Comment: @Nit - Which one is the canonical one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you writing in each, you should be writing like this, if the elements are dynamic as you mentined in comments:

```
    $(".spring_exploration").on('change','select',function() {
         var element = this;
        alert("t");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ('/admin/applications/get_sections_for_modal'), //pass query string to server
            data: {
            exploration_id: $(element).val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(element).parents('span').next().show();
                $(element).parents('span').next().find("select").html(response);
                $(element).closest(".spring_exploration") // you can access like this
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        })
    });
```

and now you can access it using `closest`

Answer (score 4):

Just store `this` in a variable. It tends to be named `that` or `me` or some other type of synonym for representing this.

```
$( ".spring_explorations" ).each(function() {
    var that = this;
       //^ store this into variable
    $("#" + this.id + " select").change(function() {
        alert("t");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ('/admin/applications/get_sections_for_modal'), //pass query string to server
            data: {
            exploration_id: $("#" + this.id + " select").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(that).parents('span').next().show();
                //^ re-use stored `this` value
                $(that).parents('span').next().find("select").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `this` from the context you want to use it in. You can use the references within nested scopes where as the value of `this` will change depending on the scope, as you have found out.

```
$( ".spring_explorations" ).each(function() {
    var _this = this;
    // You now have a reference to the node in the variable _this
    // that can be used anywhere within this functions scope

    $("#" + this.id + " select").change(function() {
        var self = this;
        // Self is now a reference to the changed element
        // that can be used within this functions scope

        // your code here that uses _this and self when you please.
    });
});
```